# Adobe AIR 3.9 minimum iOS version?

Tags: ios, ios5, air

I know that AIR V13 requires iOS 6+, but I don't know when support for iOS5 was dropped.

My google-fu has been unable to determine how the AIR versions and the iOS versions line up. Are there any resources out there, or does anyone know specifically whether AIR 3.9 supported iOS 5?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter now. If you want your app in the App Store, you need at least the most recent AIR 4.0 release. iOS 5 is now below 4% of all iOS users, I believe. With iOS 8's release on the horizon, dropping support for 5 should at least be considered (we dropped support about 6 months ago when it fell below 5%)

Comment: Thanks for the perspective Josh! Since this app is an Enterprise Deployment app, it will never hit the app store, and backward compatibility is a major concern. If we need to hit that iOS5 target, I would like to know what AIR version I have to target.

Comment: Ah, well that changes things. I don't know if Adobe keeps an archive of AIR release tech specs. You'd probably be better off asking on Adobe's forums where an Adobe Evangelist or Developer might see your question (they rarely post on StackOverflow)

Comment: Will do (re: Forums).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [thread on the Adobe AIR Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1504735), "Simply stating a minimum iOS version in the requirements page doesn't mean it technically can't still run on older versions. There was a recent post from an Adobe employee on a similar thread stating that it just means they give support for those versions a higher priority."

In fact, as of AIR 15, the minimum iOS required is **4.2.2**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use OLD Adobe AIR SDK:

1) You can't upload it to AppStore. Use only last that compatible with iOS8 (at moment of this message it's 15.0.0.302 from labs.adobe.com)

2) Actually with iOS8 you must aware anything less than 6.1 because Apple can in one day just block uploading old versions

3) Latest AIR SDK include a lot of performance improvements and reduced compiling time be 10x times!